# Почему возникает ошибка PHP Warning: Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0?

Tags: php, ubuntu, mongodb

Установил драйвер [отсюда](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver) все сделал по инструкции даже

```
$ echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

но команда `php -i | grep -i mongo` выдает

```
HP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini,
mongodb
MongoDB support => enabled
MongoDB extension version => 1.3.2
MongoDB extension stability => stable
libmongoc bundled version => 1.8.1
libmongoc SSL => enabled
libmongoc SSL library => OpenSSL
libmongoc crypto => enabled
libmongoc crypto library => libcrypto
libmongoc crypto system profile => disabled
libmongoc SASL => enabled
mongodb.debug => no value => no value
```

при чем
`extension=mongodb.so` стоит везде

```
Вопрос задан только что
```

Comment: вы `php.ini` проверьте на повторную строку, а не `php -i`. Если там два раза модуль подключен, понятное что второй раз он его не загрузит, и в списке загруженных вы повтор не увидите

Comment: ну или видимо `php_cli.ini`

Comment: Это значит что этот модуль подключён у вас в mods_enabled и где-то ещё - скорее всего в php.ini / php_cli.ini

Comment: @teran вопрос  как оно должно быть подключено только в одном php.ini (и как понять кв каком apache, cli, fpm, phpbg) или в каждом по одному разу ?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov вопрос  как оно должно быть подключено только в одном php.ini (и как понять кв каком apache, cli, fpm, phpbg) или в каждом по одному разу ?

Comment: Там принцип тот же что и в любом языке программирования - только один раз, а уже где - не важно. Запустите apache2ctl -M и посмотрите какие модули загружены, либо apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES (из https://superuser.com/questions/284898/how-to-check-which-apache-modules-are-enabled-installed)

Comment: @DanielProtopopovLoaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov
`env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
`

Comment: в конфиге для консольного приложения PHP версии 7.1 уже делается загрузка этого приложения. Читайте ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32764981/php-warning-module-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0 и следуйте аналогично в папки для вашей версии.

Comment: мне если честно помогло полное удаление extension=mongodb.so в cli/php.ini